# Можно ли динамически управлять опорным напряжением Arduino (nano)?

Tags: arduino

Можно ли динамически управлять опорным напряжением Arduino (nano). по выводу AREF? И как следствие, можно ли используя AREF задействовать Arduino как программный аудиокомпрессор?

Comment: А что документация и схема говорят по этому поводу?

Answer (score 0):

Это опорное напряжение аналого-цифрового преобразователя. Напряжение, возвращаемое функцией [analogRead()](http://arduino.ru/Reference/AnalogRead), рассчитывается относительно напряжения AREF.

Выбор источника опорного напряжения осуществляется функцией [analogReference()](http://arduino.ru/Reference/AnalogReference).

По умолчанию используется напряжение, равное напряжению питания - +5V или +3.3V.

Comment: Чуть подкорректирую мысль: При выбранном analogReference (EXTERNAL) внешнее опорное 0-5В, соответственно, введя обратную связь от источника сигнала (через резистивный делитель) на вывод AREF. можно динамически изменять Uопорн.?

Единственное, что смущает: "Замечание
После изменения аналогового опорного напряжения, первые несколько считываний с analogRead () могут быть не точными."

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю что можно. По поводу "нескольких считываний": поскольку цепь внешнего опорного имеет не идеально нулевую индуктивность/емкость, то за период стабилизации напряжения на новое значение пройдет несколько тактов считывания. Соответственно, может получиться все что угодно. Я думаю речь об этом.